# If collection of subgroups of $G$ form a chain , then $G$ is cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

If $G$ is a group such that for any two subgroups $H,K$ either $H\le K$ or $K\le H$ holds ,then $G$ is cyclic.

I am going to prove this is true for finite groups and false for infinite groups.

Proof (For finite group)

Let $G$  be a finite group satisfying the condition.

Step 1: To show $G$ must be a $p$ group.

Let $|G|$ has at least two prime factors $p$ and $q$ (say, with some powers) then a Sylow- $p$ subgroup and a Sylow- $q$ subgroup is neither a subgroup of one another and so the condition does not hold , a contradiction.

So if $G$ is finite and satisfies the condition then it is $p$ group.

Step 2: To show $G$ is cyclic

Now , let $|G|=p^n$ where $n\ge 2$

Then let $H$ be  a subgroup of order $p^{n-1}$ which exists by Sylow's Theorem.

Then let $a\in G\setminus H$ and $K=\langle a \rangle$ .

Now $K\le H$ is not possible since $a\notin H$.

So, $H\le K$ must hold. Then either $|K|=p^{n-1}$ or $p^n$.

If $|K|=p^{n-1}$ then $H=K$ which again contradicts $a\notin H$

So we must have $|K|=p^{n} \Rightarrow G=K$ which proves $G$ is cyclic.

So the result follows .

An example for falsity in infinite groups

Let $G=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : z^{2^n}=1 , n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ i.e $G$ consists of all square roots, fourth roots of unity. etc

$G$ forms a group with respect to multiplication.

Proof : Lef $z_1,z_2 \in G$

Then $z_i^{2^{n_i}}=1,i=1,2$ for some $n_1,n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$

Then $(z_1z_2)^{2^{n_1+n_2}}=(z_1^{2^{n_1}}) ^{2^{n_2}}(z_2^{2^{n_2}}) ^{2^{n_1}}  =1$

Of course, there is the identity $1$.

Let us define $A_n =\{z\in \mathbb{C} : z^{2^n}=1\}$ where $n=1,2,3.,$

These $A_n$'s form a chain of subgroups given by

$A_1 \subset A_2 \subset A_3...$

I just need to show there are no other proper subgroups.

Let $A\lt G$ and be finite.

Let $n=\displaystyle\max_i \{i: z^{2^i}=1 $  for the least  $i, z \in A\}$

Then $A_n \subseteq A$ since $A$ is a group.

The reverse  inclusion $A\subseteq A_n$ is also true by the above chain and nature of $n$

So $A=A_n$

Now  , if $A$ be infinite then the set $\{i:z^{2^i}=1 $ for the least $i ,z \in A\}$ is unbounded above and hence must it must contain $A_n$ for every $n$ which is nothing but $G$

But evidently  $G$ is not cyclic, not even finitely generated.

Is there any logical fallacy in my work? Do you have a better proof/solution ? Is ther any generalisation of this result?

Sorry if my work is clumsy as I am not used to writing sophisticated proofs. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: This is fine.${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof for finite groups is correct. However, it might be easier to point out that if $G$ is generated by $x_1,\dots,x_n$ then the subgroups $\langle x_i\rangle$ form a chain. Thus all but one of the $x_i$ is unnecessary, and $G=\langle x\rangle$.

Your example is also correct. My proof above shows that, in such a group, every finitely generated subgroup is cyclic. Such groups are called *locally cyclic*. The easiest example of a locally cyclic group is the rationals under addition, but as you can see from that, not every locally cyclic group has your property.
I'm not sure that I would accept your proof that $A=A_n$ though, as you don't seem to have demonstrated it beyond saying that it's clear. $A_n\subseteq A$ as $A$ is a group doesn't seem to make sense.

You need to note that $A_n$ contains all elements of $G$ whose order divides $2^n$. Then $A\leq A_n$ by choice of $n$, and since $A_n$ is cyclic (and generated by any element of $A_n\setminus A_{n-1}$) $A$ contains all of $A_n$, since it contains a generator of $A$, again by choice of $n$.

Notice that you may replace $2$ by $p$ in your example. These groups are called *Prüfer groups*.

Edit: Notice that you can describe your group as a quotient of the dyadic rationals. Indeed, back in the 1930s, Baer proved that every locally cyclic group (which is necessarily abelian) is a quotient of a subgroup of the rational numbers.

Comment: As user1035... points out in the other answer to this question, the Prüfer groups are the only examples of such groups.

Comment: Please clarify one or two things sir. As you said  the additive group of rationals is locally cyclic but does not satisfy the criteria . So are $(2\mathbb{Z},+)$ and $(3\mathbb{Z},+)$ suitable exmples ? Also you said every locally cyclic group is abelian. To prove that  let $G$ be locally cyclic and $a, b \in G$ , Then $\langle a, b \rangle $ is cyclic and hence $ab=ba$ . Is this correct ?

Comment: Also I wonder whether proving my group as the quotient group of the dyadic rational is trivial or non-trivial ? Do you have any hint that I should start with ? Sorry , if I have demanded more..

Comment: @user710290 $2\mathbb{Z}$ is just $\mathbb{Z}$ in disguise. And yes, your proof that locally cyclic groups are abelian is correct. Being abelian is a local property, i.e., if every $2$-generated subgroup of G is abelian then G is abelian. The same is true, for finite groups, being nilpotent or soluble. The former is not too hard, the latter is quite hard to prove. Your group is the dyadic rational modulo $1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten the finite case (since you don't actually need the prime-power order conclusion for now) by choosing $x\in G$ with $o(x)$ maximal.  Then if $\langle x\rangle\neq G$ there exists $y\in G-\langle x\rangle$ and so $\langle y\rangle$ is not contained in $\langle x\rangle$, hence $\langle x\rangle\subsetneq\langle y\rangle$, which contradicts the maximality of $o(x)$.

And in the infinite case, note that the subgroup lattice of the infinite cyclic group is not a chain.  Hence the group must be torsion, and you can now show there is some prime $p$ such that every element must have $p$-power order (if $g$ has order $n=n_1n_2$, $n_1,n_2>1$ coprime, then $\langle g^{n_1}\rangle$ and $\langle g^{n_2}\rangle$ are nontrivial and have coprime orders, so violate the chain condition).  This gives the [Prüfer groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) as the only example.

Comment: Just  clarify one thing sir. You said  an infinite group satisfying the condition can't be cyclic . Is this because  the infinite cyclic group is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and there are subgroups like $(p\mathbb{Z},+)$ and  $(q\mathbb{Z},+)$ which incomparable for different primes $p$ and $q$. Again the group has to be torsion since otherwise there would be an infinite cyclic subgroup and same argument as above. Please confirm if I am thinking correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.